# highcharts tooltip formatter only shows first 8 characters in this.point.name

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, formatter

I've been searching all day and I can't find an answer to this question. I am new to highcharts but it doesn't seem that hard to do . . .

This is what I have in the script:

```
 tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
     return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
                        }
                    },
```

I want to only show the first 8 characters from this.point.name

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use standard javascript in this function, e.g. substring().

```
 tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
         return '<b>'+ this.point.name.substring(0,7) +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
    }
},
```